# How to handle the result of a Powershell Object to call a function

Tags: function, powershell, object

Here is my code:

```
function setParameterb () {
    $Name = $args[0]  

 "Arg1: $Name"
 
}
 
Write-Output "### Starte AlertlogRotate ###" 

$folders = @('d:', 'e:', 'f:', 'g:', 'h:', 'i:', 'j:', 'k:', 'l:')

foreach ($i in $folders) {
  $filenames = Get-ChildItem -Path $i\*\log -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse -Filter alert_*.log | Select-Object FullName 
  
}
```

The setParametersb function is just for test now and should only print the result. Later, I will use it to zip logfiles which get too big.

I need to get the result of this powershell object into a string to call a function for every line.
The Object looks like this:

```
FullName                                                             
--------                                                             
D:\AREA\log\diag\rdbms\area\area\trace\alert_area.log        
D:\CONS\log\diag\rdbms\cons\cons\trace\alert_cons.log    
D:\DEV01\log\diag\rdbms\dev01\dev01\trace\alert_dev01.log            
G:\TEST01\LOG\diag\rdbms\test01\test01\trace\alert_test01.log        
G:\TEST02\log\diag\rdbms\test02\test02\trace\alert_test02.log
```

I know, that I have to crop the headline "FullName", the row"--------" and some empty lines, but this is not my problem now.
My problem is to transfer the object $filenames into an array to be able to call the function setParameterb with every single line from the output.

Comment: `$filenames |ForEach-Object { setParameterb $_.FullName }`

Comment: Hi Mathias, thank you very much. This was, what I was looking for :-)
Tried a lot of things, with conversions to strings and arrays, but this one worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried lots of other stuff, but finally this solved my problem:

```
$filenames |ForEach-Object { setParameterb $_.FullName }
```

Comment: Please mark this question as solved as you don't need any more help...

Answer (score -1):

try stuff like

```
function setParameterb () {
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $names,
)
    
foreach($name in $names){
  "Arg1: $name"
}
 
 
}
```